# Android- Schedule Asynctask to run at varying time?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I currently have an Asynctask in my Android application. I'd like to have it run at a user-defined amount of time, only when WiFi is on, only when battery is above a certain percentage, or possibly, turned off altogether, etc. (I can find examples on how to find out those bits of data, I'm sure). All the examples I see only allow for a task to be scheduled at a strict time interval.

Basically, is there any way for me to reschedule my Asynctask to execute in a certain amount of time, but just once? (It would then reschedule itself at the appropriate interval)
Or, is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: What would you perform in the asynctask for such interval? I would recommend threads and handling them for that.

Comment: Http requests and reading/writing files is what is being done. They could potentially take a few minutes.

Comment: Android Volley is the best way to go for it. It will just take you seconds / memory leak free.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AlarmManager` to keep the scheduling done. Once your receiver is called by `AlarmManager`, in its `onReceive()` you do all the checks you want. If test failed, you quit. If it passed, then you fire async task